# LINQ to SQL “Active Record” and “Unit Of Work” Pattern

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, linq-to-sql, domain-driven-design

Can you please list references for articles that demonstrates the following two, using LINQ to SQL?

1. “Active Record” Pattern
2. “Unit Of Work” Pattern

When I search for them, I am getting most of the examples clubbed with Asp.Net MVC. I don’t need MVC. I am looking for a code implementation (in LINQ to SQL) which demonstrates these two patterns.

Comment: I request the down-voters to leave a comment here :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll struggle to find references to such an idea.

To a certain extent, the LINQ to SQL is already implementing these patterns behind the scenes. Therefore, I'm not sure there's much benefit to be gained from layering the additional behavior on top.

Do you have any more detail of what you're trying to achieve that might facilitate a more useful answer?

Comment: Take a look at the conceptual overviews for each pattern:
http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html
http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html

These might help you to work out what you're trying to achieve conceptually.